# Ionic 3 keyboard status bar showing after keyboard active

Tags: android, ionic-framework, keyboard, ionic3, statusbar

I am currently using Ionic 3 and I found a pretty weird bug(?). On android I use the fullscreen option in the config.xml and also in the app.component.ts file

config.xml:

```
<preference name="FullScreen" value="true" />
```

app.component.ts:

```
keyboard.disableScroll(true);
keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
this.androidFullScreen.isImmersiveModeSupported()
    .then(() => this.androidFullScreen.immersiveMode())
    .catch((error: any) => console.log(error));
statusBar.hide();
statusBar.overlaysWebView(false);
```

And it is working well until I start using an input and when the keyboard shows up the status bars are also get visible until a minimize the app and open again.

Here is a gif about the promlem:[image]

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

So the problem was the cordova plugin not installed properly and also throw an error because of some permission thing. If this also happening with your application just run this:

```
ionic cordova build android --verbose
```

This will also throw a permission error, but it will output the folder where you don't have the right permission and after run on the folder:

```
sudo chmod 755
```